# How to set the default icon color on the selected item in bottom navigation bar in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-navigation-bar

I want the color of the icon to be the same as it but only for the selected one and some other color for the non-selected ones.

here is what I'm doing

XML:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navbar"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/button_color_black1"
    app:itemIconSize="35dp"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="selected"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/selector_for_navbar"
    app:elevation="8dp"
    app:itemRippleColor="@color/background_color"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_items_for_navbar"
    android:layout_height="70dp"/>
```

selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="x" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"  />
</selector>
```

I want x to be the same color that the icon has, and btw icon is multi-colored.
How can I do that?

Comment: To keep the original color use `bottomNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);`

Comment: but in that way, i don't get to set the color to the non selected one's